# How can I get a key => value out of this foursquare hash?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

Here is what it looks like:

```
{
  "groups" => [
    { "venues" => [
      { "city"     => "Madrid",
        "address"  => "Camino de Perales, s/n",
        "name"     => "Caja Mágica",
        "stats"    => {"herenow"=>"0"},
        "geolong"  => -3.6894333,
        "primarycategory" => {
          "iconurl"      => "http://foursquare.com/img/categories/arts_entertainment/stadium.png",
          "fullpathname" => "Arts & Entertainment:Stadium",
          "nodename"     => "Stadium",
          "id"           => 78989 },
        "geolat"   => 40.375045,
        "id"       => 2492239,
        "distance" => 0,
        "state"    => "Spain" }],
      "type"   => "Matching Places"}]
}
```

Big and ugly... I just want to grab the id out.  How would I go about doing this?

Comment: The use of arrays suggests that in reality there will be more than one group and venue. Do you want the ids of all groups and venues or just a specific one? If it's all, do you want the result as an array of arrays, a flat array, a hash, an object, or something else?

Comment: just one, that's all I search for

Comment: to know which one would be very helpfull!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

h = { "groups" => ......... }

The two ids are:

```
h["groups"][0]["venues"][0]["primarycategory"]["id"]
h["groups"][0]["venues"][0]["id"]
```

Comment: or `h["groups"][0]["venues"][0]["primarycategory"]["id"]` depending on what id he meant

Comment: Yeah, I just realized there was another one there. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the hash stores one id:(assuming the value is stored in a variable called `hash`)

```
hash["groups"][0]["venues"][0]["primarycategory"]["id"] rescue nil
```

If the hash stores multiple ids then:

```
ids = Array(hash["groups"]).map do |g|
  Array(g["venues"]).map do |v|
    v["primarycategory"]["id"] rescue nil
  end.compact
end.flatten
```

The `ids` holds the array of id's.